# Is it safe to save keyfiles in Meteor root?

Tags: json, meteor

I am working with a GA module that requires a pem file for authorisation. I first tried saving it in settings.json but I get an error that it cannot find the pemfile.

To fix this I created a server only script which loads the contents of my pem file from settings.json and writes it as a file to the meteor root.

Both are not committed to git. Is it safe to keep the pem file there or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the files in `/private` or under `/server`, not at root.